# accessing table metadata from embedded Teiid server

Tags: spring-boot, teiid

I have embedded Teiid 12.3 in a Spring Boot application. I want to get into the metadata of my VDB in order to generate a diagram using [graphviz-java](https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java). I assume that if I have a `org.teiid.metadata.Table` object, I can call `getIncomingObjects()` to get references to tables that table depends on. I just can't figure out how to navigate from the `EmbeddedServer` to the `Table` objects.

I looked into using the administration API available via `EmbeddedServer.getAdmin()`. From there, I can call `getVDBs()`, and from there I can navigate down to `getModels()`, but below that level there is only the model source via `getSourceMetadataText()`. I also tried subclassing `EmbeddedServer` to make `getVDBRepository()` public. I can call `getVDBRepository()*.getModels()`, but it returns the same `Model` objects only get me access to the source definition of the models, not the runtime metadata model.

I tried `getVDBRepository().getSystemStore()` and `VDBRepository.getODBCStore()`, but those `MetadataStore`s are not for the VDB I have deployed.

I haven't found any examples by Google, Teeid JIRA, Teiid forum, or StackOverflow to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at [1] the `getSchema` method on `Admin` API, this method returns the string form of the metadata, however you can grab `Schema` object for object form. If you do not want that way, Teiid also exposes system catalog using many `SYS` tables, you can issue SQL queries to grab the metadata of schemas and schema items in a VDB. One for internal access, another is from external access.

BTW one of users created a dependency diagram tool that may be useful if you are trying to do something similar. See [2]. Let me know if you interested in pushing that further.

[1] https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/teiid/runtime/EmbeddedAdminImpl.java#L544-L557
[2] https://github.com/teiid/metadata-catalog-ui

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the metadata-catalog-ui project. This is very helpful. I had looked at the SYS schema, and it didn't help me. I see how the project yses the SYSDAMIN.Usage table, and this is just what I need. https://github.com/teiid/metadata-catalog-ui/blob/master/src/main/java/AngularBoot/helper/ChildNodeHelper.java#L40